# Steam entry missing text in Unity 13.10 dash after upgrade

Tags: unity, launcher, icons, unity-dash, steam

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 13.10 and switched from using KDE to Unity. When I search for the program Steam in the Unity dash, it's entry (leftmost in the screenshot) does not contain any text and doesn't show the steam icon. Once I launch Steam, I have the correct icon shown in the Unity launcher. There are a handful of other applications missing icons and/or text like this.

What could be the cause?  Steam has a .desktop file that worked fine under KDE.

[image: The Steam entry in the Unity dash is missing icon and text]

Comment: Post the `.desktop` file. Probably something is wrong with `Name=` and `Icon=` lines